# Android Studio: CardView grids +content not displaying correctly in portrait mode on Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, androidx

I'm using `androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0` on Android Studio 3.5.3.
The design preview for my activity_main layout in Android Studio shows the layout perfectly [image: OnPreview]

Yet, when I test it on my device(Huawei p30 lite), the design is all messed up in the portrait mode, with no content being shown at all too

[image: OnDevice]

When viewing the layout in landscape mode on my device , it shows the design perfectly, as shown in the Android Studio preview.

Here is my code in the layout:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:src="@drawable/circle"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/fam"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/object"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp">
                    </ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"
                        android:text="Object Detection"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp">
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
                  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                  **repeat the above cardview for the remaining 5 cards**
                  .
                  </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The compilesdkversion is 28, with the minsdkversion being 23.

I have also tried setting `android:screenOrientation` to `portrait`in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and then running it on my device, but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve it.
In the `<LinearLayout>` inside each `<CardView>`, I changed the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `wrapcontent` and now it displays everything fine in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your preview device on Android Studio should match with the exact resolution on your phone.

Your Huawei Device resolution is 1080 x 2312 pixels.

Check you preview device resolution in Android studio

like this one [AS preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24tVM.png) or you can create a custom resolution same with your device phone to fix.